# How to edit the text color of 2 posts in PHP GD

Tags: php, gdlib

I want to ask, I have a web quote maker and execute code as follows,

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['execute'])) {

echo "<label>Result :</label>";

$folder = "files/quote/";
$overlay = $folder."overlay.png";
$font_quote = "files/_font/"."Ubuntu-Medium.ttf";
$font_copyright = "files/_font/"."Ubuntu-Medium.ttf";
$filename = $folder.md5(rand(000,999)).".png";
$quote = @$_POST['quote'] ? $_POST['quote'] : 'YOUR QUOTE';
$copyright = @$_POST['copyright'] ? $_POST['copyright'] : 'Username';
$backgrond = @$_POST['background'];

if (!filter_var($backgrond, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    $bg = $backgrond;
}else {    
    $bg = get_redirect_target('https://source.unsplash.com/640x640/?'.urlencode($backgrond));
}

$image = new PHPImage();
$image->setQuality(10);
$image->setDimensionsFromImage($overlay);
$image->draw($bg);
$image->draw($overlay, '50%', '75%');
$image->setFont($font_quote);
$image->setTextColor(array(255, 255, 255));
$image->setAlignVertical('center');
$image->setAlignHorizontal('center');
$image->textBox($quote, array(
    'fontSize' => 28,
    'x' => 130,
    'y' => 240,
    'width' => 380,
    'height' => 200,
    'debug' => false
    ));

$image->setFont($font_copyright);
$image->setTextColor(array(230, 209, 65)); 
$image->text('CopyRight © '.$copyright, array(
    'fontSize' => 15,
    'x' => 0,
    'y' => 535,
    'width' => 640,
    'height' => 20,
    'debug' => false
    ));
$image->save($filename);


$imagebase64 = "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
echo "<a href='".$imagebase64."' target='_blank' download='$filename'><img src='".$imagebase64."'/></a>";
unlink($filename);
}

?>
```

**Question:**

Whether in 1 the `copyright` word code can be made into 2 colors, not only 1 color, the code is still 1 color that is yellow, so if there is a submission, the color is white `Copyright ©` and yellow is the `username`?

Comment: Far too much use of the `@` error supressor. If you got erros fix em, dont ignore em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['execute'])) {

echo "<label>Result :</label>";

$folder = "files/quote/";
$overlay = $folder."overlay.png";
$font_quote = "files/_font/"."Ubuntu-Medium.ttf";
$font_copyright = "files/_font/"."Ubuntu-Medium.ttf";
$filename = $folder.md5(rand(000,999)).".png";
$quote = @$_POST['quote'] ? $_POST['quote'] : 'YOUR QUOTE';
$copyright = @$_POST['copyright'] ? $_POST['copyright'] : 'Username';
$backgrond = @$_POST['background'];

if (!filter_var($backgrond, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    $bg = $backgrond;
}else {    
    $bg = get_redirect_target('https://source.unsplash.com/640x640/?'.urlencode($backgrond));
}

$image = new PHPImage();
$image->setQuality(10);
$image->setDimensionsFromImage($overlay);
$image->draw($bg);
$image->draw($overlay, '50%', '75%');
$image->setFont($font_quote);
$image->setTextColor(array(255, 255, 255));
$image->setAlignVertical('center');
$image->setAlignHorizontal('center');
$image->textBox($quote, array(
    'fontSize' => 28,
    'x' => 130,
    'y' => 240,
    'width' => 380,
    'height' => 200,
    'debug' => false
    ));

$image->setFont($font_copyright);
$image->setTextColor(array(255, 255, 255)); 
$image->text('CopyRight © ', array(
    'fontSize' => 15,
    'x' => 0,
    'y' => 535,
    'width' => 640,
    'height' => 20,
    'debug' => false
    ));

$image->setFont($font_copyright);
$image->setTextColor(array(230, 209, 65)); 
$image->text($copyright, array(
    'fontSize' => 15,
    'x' => 100,
    'y' => 535,
    'width' => 640,
    'height' => 20,
    'debug' => false
    ));

$image->save($filename);


$imagebase64 = "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
echo "<a href='".$imagebase64."' target='_blank' download='$filename'><img src='".$imagebase64."'/></a>";
unlink($filename);
}

?>
```

If you notice, I have separated your copyright text from the username variable.
I have placed both of them on same Y axis but different X axis just like plotting on a graph.
I also gave them different colors but same font.

You can adjust the copyright X position in case 100 makes it too far or too close to the username

Comment: sorry, it didn't work, the color of the copyright and username became one ,but thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: See my updated answer. I forgot to remove the $copyright. That's why the color still remained the same